# Is there a way to cite a post other than providing the full link?

Tags: feature-request

I wonder if there is a way (e.g. a unique and stable ID), other than the full link, that one can use to cite a post, in the same vein as we can cite a journal article via its DOI.

Comment: The shortest URL that I'm aware of is the FQDN plus `/q/ID`. So the shortest URL that retrieves this question is `https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6414`.

Comment: Nice! It's not as short as I hoped but it's something...

Comment: The "share" button below a post is *almost* the shortest URL for a specific question or answer, but it has your user ID number appended to it, so it's longer than strictly necessary.

Comment: So if I want to cite, say, this post within another post X, will it work by using only the key '/q/6414' in the "link" field of post X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noticed in the comments, the shortest link is `https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6414` (this question), where the `questions/6414` part of the URL got shortened. It can be obtained from the "share" button, but it also appends your user ID creating something like `https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6414/35989` where `35989` is my user ID.

> So if I want to cite, say, this post within another post X, will it work by using only the key '/q/6414' in the "link" field of post X?

If you want to use only the string "/q/6414" as a reference then I'm afraid it would be meaningful only to a small subset of users of this site that understand how its API works. It also does not mention which StackExchange (or other) site this part of the link refers to (maybe `https://stackoverflow.com/q/6414`?). If the link needs to be useful as a reference, it needs to be meaningful for the reader.

If you need a shorter link, you can always use one of many URL-shortening services available online. For example. Bitly created `https://bit.ly/3yvSSCJ` for the link to your question. There are some downsides to URL shorteners; this article lists some of them. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pros-and-cons-of-url-shorteners/

Answer (score 7):

The use of off-site URL shorteners has been discouraged for a long time:

- [No URL Shorteners](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/113660/282094)
- [URL Shorteners cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/205806/282094)

Our official URL shortener list is here:

- [What shortened URLs are available through s.tk?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109795/282094)